# Modification of turbine tag

Tags: discussion

The current [turbine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbine) is actually describing a gas-turbine, the engine:

> A type of engine that ignites fuel in compressed air, and uses the resulting air flow for power.

When trying to tag the question: [Why are aircraft turbine blades made of nickel alloys?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/why-are-aircraft-turbine-blades-made-of-nickel-alloys) about turbine blades I found the tagging difficult as refers to the turbomachine "turbine" and not to the engine "gas-turbine".

My suggestion is to modify the name of the tag "turbine" by "gas turbine" and introduce a new tag "turbomachine turbine".

I am looking as well for advice in how to define the second tag, as maybe turbomachine turbine may be actually confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The questions currently tagged with [turbine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbine) seem to refer specifically to a turbine, not necessarily only a gas turbine ([such as the RAT](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7702/1696)). We already have specific tags for different types of engines that use a gas turbine, and I can't think of a different type of turbine that needs its own tag here.

I edited the tag wiki to make it more accurate to the general case, which seems to be how it has been applied. We can certainly discuss whether this is the best way to handle it.

Comment: Nice one. Currently there are very few questions related, I do not know if makes sense to create more specific tags as I described.

Comment: I see you created a new "blade" tag, only referring to turbines. Do we need a tag like that? How is it differentiated from other blades, like propellers?

Comment: Should be also linked to properllers.... I am thinking how to improve it. I made a modification already